# SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity At Class Level

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, unmanaged, managed

If I add the [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()] attribute to a class, is it equivalent to adding it to each function in the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSDN docs of this attribute:

> Using this attribute in a class
>   applies it to all contained methods.

So the answer to your question is yes.